# Автоинкремент в SQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql

Всем привет, скажите, вот у меня в таблице с ссылками есть их ID, ID авто увеличивается с каждым новый добавлением, но после удаления ячейка остается занята, и новая ссылка добавляется уже не как ID (то число которое удалилось), а новое.

Как можно сделать так чтобы после удаления ячейка освобождалась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно ли я понял? Есть таблица

```
Id | SomeText
1 Тест 1
2 Тест 2
3 Тест 3
4 Тест 4
```

И вы хотите, чтобы после удаления, например, id 2, новая вставляемая запись встала с id = 2, а не 5? Если это действительно так, то крайне настоятельно так не делать, потому что в этом случае вам необходимо будет самостоятельно генерировать уникальные значения (а это проблеммно) и если всё же таблица будет переполнена, проще всего сделать ALTER TABLE и поменять тип поля на более ёмкий. Тип int длиной 11, например, позволит вам забить туда около 4-х миллиардов записей.

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли. А почему так не стоит делать?

Comment: Ответил в ответ :)

Comment: Ага, спасибо.

Comment: @Angus123, еще так не стоит делать, потому что этот айдишник кто-то может ссылаться из другой таблицы, и, если соответствующим образом не заданы ограничения, после удаления/добавления вашей записи эта ссылка станет некорректной.

Comment: Такая ситуация возможна если база данных не очищается правильным образом. Например, при удалении категории товаров, удаляется только категория, а товары с ней ассоциированные остаются мусором. В остальном всё должно быть впорядке.

Answer (score 1):

Всё это уже здесь не раз обсуждалось.
Во-первых, см. ответ @Зоркий.
Во-вторых, такое решение возможно:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.[id])+1 
FROM [tbl] t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [tbl] t2 ON t2.[id] = t1.[id]+1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

За автоинкремент отвечает генератор ID, который обычно поддерживается ядром СУБД. В принципе генератор можно сделать кастомным, то есть таким как описал автор треда.

Единственное что потеряется скорость работы, поскольку в стандартной реализации ищется наибольший ID и к нему прибавляется единичка. А тут придется сортировать и искать "дырки" куда вставить ID. Не думаю, что овчинка стоит выделки.

Comment: В стандартной реализации не ищется наибольший ID. С полем таблицы связывается последовательность, и последний вставленный ID там хранится.